# Bottom:0 not working when overflow-y appear

Tags: html, css

Please look at my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LY8ze/1/

In my div have content and footer.*(2 sections)* The footer must stay at `bottom:0`.

When the scroll bar is not appearing. The footer is showing correctly. But when the scroll bar is appearing, the footer doesn't stay at bottom. You can see it in my jsFiddle as the first figure.

How can I fix that by using only css and html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is position fixed, but it will fail in your case, you need to use jQuery for this, or else you can spoof it by using a container element and than change the markup accordingly

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LY8ze/2/)

Or even a [**better solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/LY8ze/3/) (Works for both, 1st and 2nd case)

```
1.
<div class="wrap">
<div class="container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean semper sagittis velit. Cras in mi. Duis porta mauris ut ligula. Proin porta rutrum lacus. Etiam consequat scelerisque quam. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas luctus venenatis nulla. In sit amet dui non mi semper iaculis. Sed molestie tortor at ipsum. Morbi dictum rutrum magna. Sed vitae risus.
        <br />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RKA1Kkk.jpg" style="width:250px;height:150px" />
</div>
    <div class="footer">
        Author : OammieR
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#C1C2C3;
}

.wrap {
    background: #c1c2c3;
    width: 330px;

}

.footer {
    color:red;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:-

```
.footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;   // changed from absolute to relative
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: What about the section 2 in case of less content?

Answer (score 0):

may i sure try this :

CSS

```
.container {
    background-color: #C1C2C3;
    margin: 10px;
    min-height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But not working. The height of div have to limit at 250px;